# How to discharge static electricity

Tags: power-supply, electric-shock, ground

I'm building a new PC. I never cared about grounding myself because I've never had problems, but this time I don't want to take any risks.

This is a new PC that doesn't have a power supply installed yet.

Is it sufficient to touch the case without the power supply in it to ground myself? Or should I plug the power supply into the wall, turn it off and touch the power supply?

Comment: Both of your ideas are avoiding the real solution.  A grounding strap connected to earth ground.

Comment: @Ramhound the PSU is wired to a power outlet so... ? I guess the PSU casing is grounded too so I just touch that?

Comment: You asked for the proper way to do it.  You need a grounding wrist strap, connect to earth ground, in order to avoid ESD.  Simply touching the case is not enough.

Comment: touching a metallic case is a temporary solution. you may discharge if the case is at lower potential. alternatively if some static is already build on the case having higher potential than what you are carrying, you may even receive some charge. safe option is to use grounded wrist strap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The basic idea with ESD protection is to lead away any static in a controlled manner.**

This is usually done by connecting yourself and everything else to e.g. the protective earthing in a wall outlet (that has one!) in principle **via a series resistor** to make the charge dissipate **timely but slowly** (= the basic function of a wrist wrap).

To be fairly safe:

- Make your working space, table top, sink or whatever be earthed.
- Allow anything you pick up on the working space that has been away from there slight time to dissipate any static before you handle it, e.g. put the bag with electronics on the working space, before actually opening it.
- All items you work with should be in the same place
- Do not walk about, and if you have done that: touch an off-center part of the working space FIRST.
- Do not point your finger at electronics, enough static to damage electronics may jump a three foot / one meter distance if at an elevated level.
- Handle paper, plastics, clothing and similar as little as possible; better remove it from the working space all together.
- Touch PCB:s or any other electronics by edge-to-edge and away from connectors when possible.

References:
https://www.google.se/?gfe_rd=cr&safe=off#safe=off&q=esd+protection+overview

http://www.maximintegrated.com/en/app-notes/index.mvp/id/4991

http://www.esdjournal.com/